# How to create a public folder inside themes folder in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a legacy SilverStripe project. I am trying to create a public folder with the name "files" inside the themes folder. All the files within that folder will be accessible through the browser.

I created a folder and created a file within it.

[image]

When I access the file within the folder from the URL, it is giving me 404 error. But when I access the files from the other folders like css, fonts, img and so on, it is working as expected. It is just not working for "files" folder which is the one I just created. Do I need to configure something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "expose" that folders in your project's `composer.json`, so running `composer vendor-expose` will symlink or copy the files to your public resources folder.

Your composer.json will look like this:

```
{
    "name": "app/myproject",
    "type": "silverstripe-project",
    "require": {
        "silverstripe/recipe-cms": "4.4.x-dev"
    },
    "extra": {
        "resources-dir": "_resources",
        "expose": [
            "themes/mytheme/dist",
            "themes/mytheme/files"
        ]
    }
}
```

It's good practice to collect all generated exposable files (js, css) in a folder called "dist", this way you don't have to expose them seperately.

You can call `composer vendor-expose` manually (e.g. on windows after every file change cause symlinks won't work under windows) and it's called automatically whenever you run `composer install` or `composer update`.

[See docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/requirements/#configuring-your-project-exposed-folders).